# Java Rest Template

Tags: java, resttemplate

```
 ResponseEntity<BaseDto> entity =  restTemplate.getForEntity("/get/code/IN", BaseDto.class);
     System.out.println("entity : " + entity);
         System.out.println("entity.getBody() : " + entity.getBody());  
     System.out.println(entity.getBody().getResponseObject());
```

As per above rest am getting below format:

```
{
    systemTrack=
    {
    createUser=admin, 
    createDate=2016-03-01 18:11:17, 
    lastUpdatedUser=admin, 
    lastUpdatedDate=2016-03-01 18:11:17

}, 

countryCode=IN, countryName=INDIA

}
```

How to get the values from this format?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I was unclear with my question, but i got a solution through debug mode.
It was a format which is in Linked hash map ,so what I did was I just wrote below code for json conversion of LinkedHashMap.

```
LinkedHashMap m = (LinkedHashMap) object;
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(m);(package of org.json.JSONObject)
 and then i assigned to  custom class object using 
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
String jsonString = jsonObject.toString();
Object obj = gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);
```